# Custom Keyboard for Multiple Text fields

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios4

How can I use a custom keypad I have made with multiple text fields.

So far I can do it for one but not for the others.

Following is my code for the 'C' button on my customer keypad but only works for `textFieldLoanAmount`

```
-(IBAction) clearAll:(id)sender{

currentValue = 0.0;
[stringValue setString:@""];
textFieldLoanAmount.text = @"0";
dotPressed = NO;
```

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should have some sort of a property that points to the currently active text field?

Comment: That's what I do, I use the textFieldShouldBeginEditing: delegate method to set a currently active textField property on my ViewController.

Comment: so do you mean something like this:
`textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
        }`

Comment: Yes, in textFieldShouldBeginEditing you just do something like self.activeTextField = textField and then in your clearAll replace textFieldLoanAmount with self.activeTextField. That is assuming clearAll is your UITextFieldDelegate. If not, just pass the textField from the delegate to the whatever object actually modifies the fields.